# Validating pyramid requests

Tags: python, redirect, pyramid

I have a pyramid application with many defined routes.  I want to do a few different server-side checks whenever a user makes a request and possibly redirect the request if certain criteria are met.

I realize I could add these checks to each of the view functions, but I'd like to avoid having to update and add boilerplate to dozens of view functions.

Is there a way in pyramid to perform some checks for all requests, **before** they're sent onto the view functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a [NewRequest](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/events.html#pyramid.events.NewRequest) event:

```
from pyramid.events import NewRequest
from pyramid.events import subscriber

@subscriber(NewRequest)
def new_request_subscriber(event):
    validate_request(event.request)
```

More information in the offical docs:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/events.html